# eclipse - Cannot resolve selected text to a defined function or member

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Im using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version Oxygen.2 Release(4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600

Im trying to use the "Open Call Hierarchy" but I keep getting this error:
"Cannot resolve selected text to a defined function or member"
Ive reindexed the whole project multiple times, using right-click on the project name -> Index -> Freshen all files.
aswell as delete the project and reImport it. still no progress.
and Idead what causes this problem?
thanks.

Comment: It could be related to the project configuration, or to the code. It's hard to tell which based on this description. Can you share some example code that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This happens when Eclipse has not yet finished indexing the source code. Giving it some time will result in building the index and cross-reference. This will resolve the issue